# How does one go about acquiring access to twitter's streaming sample firehose?

Tags: twitter

I've been looking this up for the last few days now, and it appears as if twitter does have a sample firehose (lets just call it a garden hose) of 1% of tweets out there somewhere, but I cannot figure out how to access it.  Is it just their statuses/firehose endpoint?  Or is there another one?

If it is that one, how would I go about asking for access?  I cannot find a link to request access or any information on it?

I would like to test a theory before paying a fortune on firehose access through GNIP.

If this isn't the right place to post this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's Public API provides the 1% access you refer to via the Streaming API. The [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) are pretty thorough, and some Google-fu will help you fill in the gaps.

The "gardenhose" was a term used to refer to the 10% access that Twitter provided to some academics and other entities on per case basis.

At present, [Gnip](http://gnip.com), which is now owned by Twitter, offers both Firehose (100%), and Decahose (10%) real-time streaming access. It goes without saying that both of those offerings are not free. Firehose access is also available from Datasift.